# undefined reference to GoadlIDGenerator

Tags: ros-industrial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am currently working with ros-industrial and an Adept robot-arm.

I am trying to use a code I found on ros-industrial but I have some issues with it.

The code ist he joint_trajectory_action.cpp file from http://swri-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/branches/groovy/adept/adept_common/src/

The error I get is at the end

```
astro@astro-1106B5G:~/catkin_kevin$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/astro/catkin_kevin
Source space: /home/astro/catkin_kevin/src
Build space: /home/astro/catkin_kevin/build
Devel space: /home/astro/catkin_kevin/devel
Install space: /home/astro/catkin_kevin/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/astro/catkin_kevin/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/astro/catkin_kevin/build"
####
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target trajectory_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  7%] Built target industrial_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  8%] Built target simple_message_dummy
[  9%] [ 10%] Built target industrial_utils
Built target industrial_robot_client_dummy
[ 11%] [ 16%] Built target industrial_trajectory_filters
[ 20%] Built target adept_common_generate_messages_lisp
Built target adept_common_generate_messages_py
[ 23%] Built target adept_common_generate_messages_cpp
[ 32%] [ 32%] Built target industrial_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target adept_common_generate_messages
[ 38%] Built target industrial_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 38%] Built target industrial_msgs_generate_messages
[ 53%] Built target simple_message_bswap
[ 68%] Built target simple_message_float64
[ 83%] Built target simple_message
Scanning dependencies of target joint_trajectory_action_1
[ 88%] Built target industrial_robot_client_bswap
[ 89%] [ 91%] Built target motion_interface
[ 92%] Building CXX object adept_common/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_action_1.dir/src/joint_trajectory_action.cpp.o
Built target robot_state_1
[ 95%] [ 96%] [ 96%] Built target industrial_robot_client
Built target motion_streaming_interface_bswap
Built target motion_download_interface_bswap
[ 97%] Built target robot_state_bswap
[ 98%] [100%] Built target joint_trajectory_action
Built target motion_download_interface
[100%] Built target motion_streaming_interface
[100%] Built target robot_state
Linking CXX executable /home/astro/catkin_kevin/devel/lib/adept_common/joint_trajectory_action_1
CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_action_1.dir/src/joint_trajectory_action.cpp.o: dans la fonction « actionlib::ActionServerBase<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >::ActionServerBase(boost::function<void (actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, boost::function<void (actionlib::ServerGoalHandle<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >)>, bool) »:
joint_trajectory_action.cpp:(.text._ZN9actionlib16ActionServerBaseIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC2EN5boost8functionIFvNS_16ServerGoalHandleIS4_EEEEESB_b[_ZN9actionlib16ActionServerBaseIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC5EN5boost8functionIFvNS_16ServerGoalHandleIS4_EEEEESB_b]+0xa5): référence indéfinie vers « actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::GoalIDGenerator() »
CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_action_1.dir/src/joint_trajectory_action.cpp.o: dans la fonction « actionlib::StatusTracker<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >::StatusTracker(boost::shared_ptr<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&) »:
joint_trajectory_action.cpp:(.text._ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC2ERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS1_32FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal_IS3_EEEE[_ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC5ERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS1_32FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal_IS3_EEEE]+0x60): référence indéfinie vers « actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::GoalIDGenerator() »
joint_trajectory_action.cpp:(.text._ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC2ERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS1_32FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal_IS3_EEEE[_ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC5ERKN5boost10shared_ptrIKNS1_32FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal_IS3_EEEE]+0xbb): référence indéfinie vers « actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::generateID() »
CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_action_1.dir/src/joint_trajectory_action.cpp.o: dans la fonction « actionlib::StatusTracker<control_msgs::FollowJointTrajectoryAction_<std::allocator<void> > >::StatusTracker(actionlib_msgs::GoalID_<std::allocator<void> > const&, unsigned int) »:
joint_trajectory_action.cpp:(.text._ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC2ERKN14actionlib_msgs7GoalID_IS3_EEj[_ZN9actionlib13StatusTrackerIN12control_msgs28FollowJointTrajectoryAction_ISaIvEEEEC5ERKN14actionlib_msgs7GoalID_IS3_EEj]+0x5c): référence indéfinie vers « actionlib::GoalIDGenerator::GoalIDGenerator() »
collect2: erreur: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[2]: *** [/home/astro/catkin_kevin/devel/lib/adept_common/joint_trajectory_action_1] Erreur 1
make[1]: *** [adept_common/CMakeFiles/joint_trajectory_action_1.dir/all] Erreur 2
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

It concern apparently the GoalIDGenerator reference which is undefined. I know that this code was supposed to work on ROS groovy, can you tell me what I need to change in it ?

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209079/undefined-reference-to-goadlidgenerator/) by [Hkev68](https://answers.ros.org/users/22313/hkev68/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not too sure about the actual error you are getting, but as to the Adept package(s): you're using `catkin_make`, but the Adept packages have not been migrated to catkin yet. In fact, the Adept packages have not seen too much (read: none) development at all since they were first released.

They can most likely be made to work again, but it will require some TLC.

I'd advise you to first contact the ROS-Industrial [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/swri-ros-pkg-dev) to get some more first-hand information on the state of those packages, and what would is needed to get them going again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0